# connect with sql server from android throw web service WCf

Tags: java, android, sql-server, wcf, web-services

I spent lot of time to connect with local Database throw jdbcOdbcDrivr. Many people advice me to connect with database from android app throw web service. WCF is great solution for making web services , i do that and publish the web services to local IIS sever.

When i use the direct

```
url 192.168.0.1:90/Service1.svc/checkLogin?name=a&pass=1
```

it works fine.

When i used from andriod app

```
HttpGet httpGet=new HttpGet(
    "192.168.0.1:90/Service1.svc/checkLogin?name='"+UserName+"'&pass='"+Password);
```

It did not work.

Please tell what can i do to fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

how about adding: "http://" before this: 192.168.0.1:90/Service1.svc/checkLogin?name='"+UserName+"'&pass='"+Password

so you will have:

```
http://192.168.0.1:90/Service1.svc/checkLogin?name='"+UserName+"'&pass='"+Password
```

Comment: HttpGet httpGet=new HttpGet("http://192.168.0.1:90/Service1.svc/checkLogin?name='"+UserName+"'&pass='"+Password);

     HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

                   When I debug my app , it's go to 

              catch(Exception e)
     {
      return false;
     }
        
                when it came to these line 

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

Comment: the error is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost:90 refused

Comment: do not use localhost when it comes to coding in android. since android itself uses localhost. Instead use the ip address. and add http:// before the ip address

Comment: When I use Ip address it go to Exception handling and these is detial:""""

failed to connect to /192.168.112.134 (port 90): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.112.134:90 refused

Comment: Please can any help me

Comment: a connection timed out error means that the request could not be fulfilled within a particular time period, and connection to IP Address refused means that it simply could not connect to the service at all. Please post in atleast that portion of the code if possible, and also ensure that whatever you are testing from is also within the same network as the IP Address.

Comment: System.out.println("guru");
DefaultHttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpGet httpGet=new httpGet("http://192.168.112.134:90//Service1.svc/checkLogin?name='"+UserName+"'&pass='"+Password);
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
InputStream stream=httpEntity.getContent();
String result= convertStreamToString(stream);
if(result.charAt(1)=='1')
{
return true;
}
            else
            {
             return false;
            }

Comment: could you replace this line :
HttpGet httpGet=new httpGet("192.168.112.134:90//Service1.svc/…);

with (PS: There is **http://**  before the IP Address)

HttpGet httpGet=new httpGet("http://192.168.112.134:90/Service1.svc/…);

Comment: I used but when post the comment it's not apper

Comment: why do you need these single quotes name= **'** "+UserName+" **'** ??? Also check if there is no firewall blocking this request. or an antivirus involved

Comment: I remove the single code and stop the firewall But still have the same problem

Comment: this code in my web config of WCF

<identity>
<dns value="localhost" />
</identity>

Mabye be make problem??????????

Answer (score 0):

Note if you are using android emulator, and your web services is running on a  local IIS server, you must add your ip host to your android host file look this  http://mcilvena.com/articles/modify-android-host-file/

Comment: Iam Not using emulatour to run my android app

Comment: Then look if you can use, the ip host like 10.0.2.2 or 10.0.0.2 that is the same that 127.0.0.1 when used in computer.